# Retrieving data from NSUserDefaults crashes app

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have been using NSUserDefaults to store an array however I have been having issues with my app crashing when trying to retrieve data.

Basically I have this line of code in viewWillAppear:

```
        presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSMutableArray
```

When I tap on the button that will make this view appear, my app crashes. There is no error in the console.

I'm sure the issue is obvious, but I've tried a few things with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had forgotten that you cannot store an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults. I just converted it like this:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    presetNames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("presets") as NSArray
    presetNamesMutable = presetNames.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
}
```